# User not appearing when I start typing name in Group

Tags: 2013, active-directory, user-profile-service

There are 3 users in AD and they are synced with UPS. I can see their profile and if I do people search then they also appear in results. Let's call them user1, user2, user3.
Problem is I am trying to add them in a SharePoint security group but their names don't appear as I start typing "user".
I am able to add all other users except these. What could be the issue?